# Java guess game. How do I input data validation(range checking) and how do I input guesses?

Tags: java

I have a project Im working on for class. Its a guessing game that gets a random number and the user guesses what it is. Ive got a working version of the project, but according to my instructions, it needs data validation(range checking would be best) and it also needs to display a certain message depending on how many tries it takes the user to guess correctly. If its less than 3, it should say something like "Good job!" If its more than 3 but less than 7, it should say something like "Need more practice." If its more than 7 it should say something like "Need way more practice." I dont want to have to de-construct my whole project, I would like to just add into it, and tweak accordingly. Can someone give me a way of coding these things?

Heres my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGameCalc {

    private static void displayWelcomeMessage(int max) {
       System.out.println("Welome to the Java Guessing Game!");
       System.out.println(" ");
       System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and" + " " + max);
       System.out.println(" ");   
    }  

    public static int calculateRandomValue(int max){
       double value = (int) (Math.random() * max + 1);
       int number = (int) value;
       number++;
       return number;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final int max = 100;
        String prompt = "y";
        displayWelcomeMessage(max);
        int unit = calculateRandomValue(max);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 1;

        while (prompt.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number.");  
                int userEntry = sc.nextInt();

                if (userEntry < 1 || userEntry > max) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid guess! Guess again!");
                    continue;
                }

                if (userEntry < unit) {
                    System.out.println("Too low! Guess higher!");
                }else if (userEntry > unit) {
                    System.out.println("Too high! Guess lower!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed it in" + " " + counter + " " + "tries!\n");
                    break;
                }
                counter++;
            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to try again? Yes or No?");

            prompt = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
       }
    } 

   public static void validateTheData() { }
}
```

Comment: Are you twins ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58161237/java-guess-game-how-do-i-use-data-validation-to-check-if-a-number-is-within-a-c

Answer (score 0):

Seems all you need to do is passing counter variable to validateTheData method and output your message, like this:

```java
...
while (true) {
  System.out.println("Please enter a number.");

  int userEntry = sc.nextInt();

  if (userEntry < 1 || userEntry > max) {
    System.out.println("Invalid guess! Guess again!");
    continue;
  }

  if (userEntry < unit) {
    if( (unit - userEntry) > 10 ){
      System.out.println("Way Too low! Guess higher!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Too low! Guess higher!");
    }
  } else if (userEntry > unit) {
    if( (userEntry - unit) > 10 ){
      System.out.println("Way Too high! Guess lower!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Too high! Guess lower!");
    }
  } else {
    validateTheData(counter);
    break;
  }
  counter++;
}
...
```

```java
public static void validateTheData(int count) {
  if( count < 3){
    System.out.println("Good job!");
  } else if( count < 7 ){
    System.out.println("Need more practice.");
  } else{
    System.out.println("Need way more practice.");
  }
}
```

Comment: That is an example I needed, thank you. Another thing is that my "validateTheData" method has an error that reads "class, interface, or enum expected" and I dont know how to fix it. Every time I try to add or get rid of curly brackets, it wont work.

Comment: @Teknomancer you may need to post your complete code, and java version info.

Comment: The above code is the entire code. The code you put works, but its not letting me put it underneath the main method for whatever reason. And Im still grappling with trying to code the instructions that say "If the user’s guess is more than 10 higher or 10 lower than the random number, the application should display, “Way too high!” or “Way too low!”  And Im using NetBeans 11, Java with Maven

Comment: I‘m confused, does your "display certain message" problem solved? if you are talking about a different problem, claim it clearly.

Comment: I have the "display certain message" problem, which says the program needs to display a certain message depending on how many tries it takes the user to guess correctly. If its less than 3, it should say something like "Good job!" If its more than 3 but less than 7, it should say something like "Need more practice." If its more than 7 it should say something like "Need way more practice."  I am also having the problem that says If the user’s guess is more than 10 higher or 10 lower than the random number, the program should display, “Way too high!” or “Way too low!” Im trying to solve both.

Comment: I entered and tweaked the code, it works. But a minor problem I had since before you helped me is that It displays "Goodbye" and then "Please enter a number." It should only display "goodbye" when the user types anything other than a Y or a y when asked if they want to continue.

Comment: Hi dude,do not turn a question into an chatroom.more question, make another post

Comment: remember to accept the answer as it solved your original and second question, thanks