# Java guess game. How do I use data validation to check if a number is within a certain range?

Tags: java

I need help coding a set of statements of data validation that checks if a user entry is within a range of 0 and 100, and anything the user types that ISNT a non-decimal integer between 1 and 100 should display an error message. Also I need a way to code how I can get a "goodbye" output to only display if the user enters "n" not "n" and "y." N meaning no and y meaning yes.

Heres my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGameCalc {

    private static void displayWelcomeMessage(int max) {

        System.out.println("Welome to the Java Guessing Game!");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and" + " " + max + " " + "let's see if you guess what it is!");
        System.out.println(" ");

    }  

    public static int calculateRandomValue(int max) {

      double value = (int) (Math.random() * max + 1);
      int number = (int) value;
      number++;
      return number;
    }

    public static void validateTheData(int count) {
        if( count < 3) {
            System.out.println("Good job!");
        } else if (count < 7) {
            System.out.println("Need more practice.");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Need way more practice.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int max = 100;
        String prompt = "y";
        displayWelcomeMessage(max);
        int unit = calculateRandomValue(max);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 1;

        while (prompt.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number.");

                int userEntry = sc.nextInt();

                if (userEntry < 1 || userEntry > max) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid guess! Guess again!");
                    continue;
                }

                if (userEntry < unit) {
                    if ( (unit - userEntry) > 10 ) {
                        System.out.println("Way Too low! Guess higher!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Too low! Guess higher!");
                    }
                } else if (userEntry > unit) {
                    if( (userEntry - unit) > 10 ){
                        System.out.println("Way Too high! Guess lower!");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Too high! Guess lower!");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Congratulations! You guessed it in" + " " + counter + " " + "tries!\n");
                    validateTheData(counter);
                    break;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to try again? Yes or No?");
            prompt = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either use [`sc.hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--)  to check for valid numeric input, or be prepared to catch the `InputMismatchException` that `sc.nextInt()` will throw in the event of a non-numeric input.

Comment: Twins perhaps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58160082/java-guess-game-how-do-i-input-data-validationrange-checking-and-how-do-i-inp

Comment: fyi, by incrementing `number ` in your `calculateRandomValue()` method, it returns values in the range `2` to `max + 1`. My guess is that is not your intention.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.nextInt()` rather use `.nextLine()`, which returns a `String` and then parse it to an `int` and catch the `NumberFormatException`

So basically you'll have this structure:

```
try {
    int userEntry = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    ...
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid number.");
}
```

Oh, just a comment on the rest of your code. You don't really need two `while` loops, one will be more than sufficient.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If it did, please check the box to mark it as resolved.